# Is there any equation to predict the salting out concentration of a polymer?

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution

I have to roughly calculate the salting out concentration of a polymer with respect to NaOH.

Is there any method to calculate?

Comment: There is a method, using  diagrams and/or empirical equations. It is universal, applicable to all  systems. It is not in favour, as it has unknown parameter values, particular for particular systems, that have to be gathered experimentally.